# Can't diagnose Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have recently been working on creating a MMO in java and have stumbled upon a issue that i cant diagnose. About 50% of the time the program will null pointer just after a character has been selected on this line

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
if (getActiveState() != null) {
            g.drawImage(getActiveState().render().gameImage, 0, 0,     window.getWidth(), window.getHeight(), null);
            getActiveState().renderUI(g);// this line null pointers
        }
    }
```

As the line above works fine i can assume it is not the getActiveState() method that is causing the problem so it must be the renderUI() method.

```
public void renderUI(Graphics g) {
    ui.render(g);
}
```

The ui class is initialized in the constructor for the state so it cant be null. So the only thing left to check is the ui's render method.

```
public void render(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < containers.size(); i++) {
        if (containers.get(i) == null) {
            System.out.println("null container");
        }
        if (containers.get(i).isVisible() && containers.get(i) != null) {
            containers.get(i).render(g);
        }

    }
}
```

As you can see there is nothing here that could null pointer other than the containers list however that is also initialized in the constructor for the UI so it cant be null either.

If anyone can spot anything I have missed or knows what is causing this it would be a great help.

Edit:
the exact error is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at genesis.GameLoop.render(GameLoop.java:129)
at genesis.GameLoop.run(GameLoop.java:100)
at genesis.GameWindow.<init>(GameWindow.java:25)
at genesis.GameWindow.main(GameWindow.java:64)
```

Line 129 is the renderUI line.

Comment: Could you add the exact output of your exception stack trace to your question?

Comment: Could we get the `stacktrace` and the line that it pointed to ?

Comment: please update your question and post the full stack trace of your NullPointerException. and indicate the exact line where NPE is thrown.

Comment: I hope you know, that the `containers` list could contain `null` elements ...

Comment: Are you sure containers.get(i) is not returning null?

Comment: Its definatly not the containers returning null, i have done a lot of testing on it and it doesnt get that far

Comment: `if (containers.get(i).isVisible() && containers.get(i) != null)` You can omit that null check here, because it won't help at this position.

Comment: *"As the line above works fine i can assume it is not the getActiveState() method that is causing the problem so it must be the renderUI() method."* This is wrong. If the `renderUI` method would be the problem, then the `NullPointerException` would occur there and not in the `render` method. So you should stop assuming that `getActiveState()` is ok, because it returns `null` and causes your problem.

Comment: I think i may have found the problem, if the ui is clicked at a certain point then it will attempt to render in between the states being set as it is a seperate thread from the mouse handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was being an idiot and had issues with threading. When the mouse was clicked on the UI the mouse handler would call the onclick method of the uiComponent in a separate thread which meant that the game would attempt to render in between the states being changed.